# Gettinf Property **text** not found error in DataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, itemeditor

I am using a custom itemEditor for my DataGrid.
The itemEditor has a simple TextField as a component.
But when ever i am clicking the cell i am getting an error as :
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property **text** not found on editors.customItemEditor and there is no default value.
 at mx.controls::DataGrid/itemEditorItemEditEndHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\controls\DataGrid.as:4827]

Plz help me to resolve this issue.

My Opinion is that the error is coming for  the "text" field. But i havn't accessed "text" field or used it anywhere in my code.

Regards,
Ravi

Answer (score 1):

i solved the problem with commiting incluting "return data["selected"].toString()" into get text:

```
    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="selected" rendererIsEditor="true" >
            <mx:itemRenderer> 
                <fx:Component>
                    <mx:Box styleName="" width="100%" height="100%" backgroundAlpha="0.0"
                            horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">

                        <fx:Script>
                            <![CDATA[

                                public function get text():String
                                {
                                    return data["selected"].toString();
                                }
                                public function set text(value:String):void
                                {

                                }
                                protected function checkbox1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
                                {
                                    data["selected"]=event.target["selected"];
                                }
                            ]]>
                        </fx:Script>

                        <mx:CheckBox selected="{data.selected}" click="checkbox1_clickHandler(event)"/>
                    </mx:Box>
                </fx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>              
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Taken from http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=celleditor_8.html

> By default, Flex expects an item editor to return a single value to the list-based control. You use the editorDataField property of the list-based control to specify the property of the item editor that contains the new data. Flex converts the value to the appropriate data type for the cell.
> The default item editor is a TextInput control. Therefore, the default value of the editorDataField property is "text", which corresponds to the text property of the TextInput control. If you specify a custom item editor, you also set the editorDataField property to the appropriate property of the item editor

Answer (score 0):

I am still Struck in this error but i think there is a hope of coming out of it.... :)

If we take TextInput as the itemEditor, like:

```
dataGridColumn.itemEditor = new ClassFactory(TextInput);
```

Then there was no problem as "text" is being internally defined inside TextInput.as.
On a similar note if i copy set text and get text inside our custom Editor, then its working fine.. only problem that is
coming is regarding commiting the changed values.

I am working on it, hope i'll be able to sort it out.

P.S.: I am a newbie here, so plz pardon me of any idiotic RnD... :p